# Segmentation Fault With Pointers In Sorted Lists In C

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have a function here that destroys an iterator acting on a sorted list.

```
void SortedListDestroyTheIterator (SortedListIteratorPtr iter) 
{
    Node pt = NULL;
    Node prev = NULL;
    SortedListIteratorPtr walk;

    walk = malloc(sizeof(struct SortedListIterator)+1);
    SortedListPtr li = iter->list;

    for(pt = li->start; pt!=NULL; pt = pt->next) //problem line of code
    {
        walk = pt->info;
        //delete
        if(walk==iter){
            if(prev==NULL){
                li->start = li->start->next;
            }
            else
            {
                prev->next = pt->next;
            }
        }
        prev = pt;
    }
    free(iter);
}
```

I have figured out that a segmentation fault occurs with this assignment statement: `pt = li->start`. Now this line of code is creating a node that points to the starting node of the list. If I type in `li->start` it works, but once I add the assignment `pt=li->start` I get a segmentation fault. I do not understand why or how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is Node a node or a pointer to node? If Node is a structure, then the code should be:

```
Node * pt = NULL;
Node * prev = NULL;
```

Although if this fix works, I don't understand why the compiler didn't produce an error or warning.

The example code doesn't show how Node, SortedListPtr, SortedListIterator, or SortedListIteratorPtr are defined.

I didn't check to see if there are other issues.

Answer (score 0):

The line `pt = NULL` seems the culprit.

Look in the for loop code:

> for(pt = li->start; pt!=NULL; **pt = pt->next** ) //problem line of code

Comment: As long as li->start != NULL, the for loop should be ok.